# Proof $a_{n}$ by induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

This topic is a continuation of [Prove that $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432349/prove-that-a-n-a-n-1-a-n-2).

I need to prove that $a_{n} = (\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n} + (\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

This is how I tried to prove this.

Basic step: $a_{1} = (\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1} + (\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}$ which is equal to $2$ and is correct.

Inductive step: Let $k \geq 1$ and let the statement apply to each $k$ where $1 \geq j \geq k$. From the previous topic we know that $a_{k} = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}$ and so that $a_{k+1} = a_{k} + a_{k-1}$. Because of the hypothesis we know that the statement applies for $a_{k}$ and $a_{k-1}$. As $a_{k+1}$ exists of the sum of $a_{k}$ and $a_{k-1}$, we can conclude that the statement also applies for $a_{k+1}$.

Is this proof by induction valid?

Comment: What are you looking for is "Solving homogeneous linear recurrence relations". For in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than solve the problem through the standard methods for more general linear recurrences, I'll address your questions about induction:

1. Your choice of induction hypothesis is right. We already know that $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ for all $n\geq 1$ from your previous question. Here you want to assume that $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ can be written explicitly as
   $$a_{n+1}=\left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1} + \left(\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
   and
   $$a_n=\left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n} + \left(\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}$$
   respectively. Using that and the fact that $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ you want to show that $a_{n+2}$ can be written in the same way, only with $n+2$ in the corresponding exponents. This is a matter of simple algebraic manipulation: write out the sum, factor out $\lambda_\pm=\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$ and note that these numbers are roots of $x^2=x+1$ as @lhf pointed out.
2. That brings us to the following problem: when $n=1$, we have $a_3=a_2+a_1$. This means that $a_1$ is not the only base case: you need to prove $a_2$ as a base case as well. More generally: if your inductive step $P(n)$ depends on $P(n-1),P(n-2),...,P(n-k)$, then you need to prove $k$ base cases. See the Wikipedia page on [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear. I only don't understand why the roots helped proving the case.

Comment: If we write $\alpha_\pm=\frac{5\pm 3\sqrt 5}{10}$ and $\lambda_\pm=\frac{1\pm \sqrt 5}{2}$, then $a_{n+1}+a_n=\alpha_+(\lambda_+^{n+1}\lambda_+^n)+\alpha_-(\lambda_-^{n+1}+\lambda_-^n)=\alpha_+\lambda_+^n(\lambda_++1)+\alpha_-\lambda_-^n(\lambda_-+1)$. But since $\lambda_\pm$ are roots of $x^2=x+1$, we have $\lambda_\pm^2=\lambda_\pm+1$. Then $\alpha_+\lambda_+^n(\lambda_++1)=\alpha_+\lambda_+^n(\lambda_+^2)=\alpha_+\lambda_+^{n+2}$ and similarly for $\lambda_-$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with $a_{0} = 1$ and $a_{1}=2$.

Let $b_{n} = (\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n} + (\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n}$.

To prove that $a_n=b_n$, it is enough to prove that $b_{n} = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ with $b_{0} = 1$ and $b_{1}=2$.

- $b_{0} = 1$ and $b_{1}=2$ is immediate.
- $b_{n} = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ follows from the fact that $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} $ are roots of $x^2=x+1$.

Comment: Well, this is induction: $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.